# Formating issue with dump in 0.17.16-1

Tags: ruamel.yaml

I have a YAML file that is usually edited by a human but, recently I have a need for it to also be edited by an automated task.  I am using version `0.17.16-1` from the Ubuntu repo. I have mostly figured out how to get the output to look like the input with one exception.  When there is a comment in my YAML right before an array, the first element is mis-formatted.  If I remove the comment, the formatting is correct. It also doesn't matter if the comment is left-justified or indent like in the example. Most likely, I have something mis-configured so, if anyone could point it out to me I'd be very grateful.  This has been driving me nuts for a few days now.

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
top_level:
  # comment
  -
    key1: "1"
    key4: "4"
  -
    key2: "2"
    key5: "5"
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.compact(seq_map=False)
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

Output:

```
top_level:
  # comment
  -
    key1: '1' key4: '4'
  -
    key2: '2'
    key5: '5'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ruamel.yaml` attaches comments normally to the node **preceding** the comment,
so you are not having a comment before a sequence (no arrays in YAML), but a comment
between a key and its value. Those can be problematic, but the main problem here
seems to be the use of `yaml.compact()` in combination with the comment:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
top_level:
  # comment
  -
    key1: "1"
    key4: "4"
  -
    key2: "2"
    key5: "5"
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True            # this way you keep double quotes from the input
# yaml.compact(seq_map = False)
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
top_level:
  # comment
  - key1: "1"
    key4: "4"
  - key2: "2"
    key5: "5"
```

If the above really does have to have block sequence indicator on a line of its own, you can
trivially postprocess the output with the `transform` parameter of `dump()`.

You should be using a Python virtual environment, and never work in the system
Python space. That allows you to install newer versions of all packages than the
system uses.